# Label showing "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label"

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
double peratusE = ((double)(bilanganE / calonAmbil)) * 100.00;
                    Label peratusELabel = row.Cells[16].FindControl("peratusELabel") as Label;
                    peratusELabel.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", peratusELabel);
```

i use that particular code to calculate the percentage and to assign the percentage value to a label. however, when running it, it displays "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label" instead of the value.

for your information: i use

```
double peratusD = ((double)(bilanganD / calonAmbil)) * 100.00;
                    Label peratusDLabel = row.Cells[14].FindControl("peratusDLabel") as Label;
                    peratusDLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", peratusD);
```

but this time it works just fine. i'm stucked.

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code (debugging)? that might give you an insight on why it's not returning the text correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
peratusELabel.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", peratusE);
```

In your first code block you are formatting a `Label` object, not a `double` object.

Comment: Not a problem :) we all make mistakes!